# need dell studio 1557 webcam driver

Tags: drivers, webcam, dell-studio

I need Dell Studio 1557 webcam driver.i can not find this driver in [Dell Drivers and Downloads](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/index.aspx) page.

Comment: It might be part of the Dell System Software, found under System Utilities. Which OS?

Comment: No,I installed Dell System Software but Dell Webcam central error:No support webcam driver detect! win 7 x64.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried searching Windows update for the driver? I've never seen Windows 7 fail to install a webcam out of the box.

I found the install files from the CD, and can't seem to find a driver at all, which to me says it's assumed the system will take care of it.

Does it show up in the device manager?

Comment: There are many HP models that have this problem also, I have yet to figure out why W7 does not detect and install a image device driver.

Comment: driver installed in device manager,but Dell webcam central cannot detect this.

Comment: This is right, I have a Dell Studio 1558, I believe the 1557 and 1558 have the same Webcam + Driver, there was no need for installation of any driver as Windows 7 took care of that for me. Just load up Skype or go to http://www.testwebcam.com/ to see if your webcam is detected

Comment: @SandeepBansal +1 for nice link